# How to create a routable network with PGRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, network

I have two sets of data

Table A: Stations - contains postal code (which I can convert to lat/long), name and code.
Table B: Connections - contains a possible list of connections including source, target (both expressed as three letter codes), distance and maximum speed (I can calculate a cost from these two parameters).

I want to create a routable network - from looking, I have found PGRouting may be able to do what I need but almost all the tutorials I've found are based on road networks.

What is the best way to convert the data I have into a routable network? I'm not set on PostGIS/PGRouting but I haven't found a better solution yet - eventually there'll be around 3000 stations and 5000+ connections.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem using PgRouting for this purpos, and it should be pretty straight forward to prepare your data as routable network.

I build a network similar to yours based on transtools data for Europe, and it was working within an hour. Load the data into the database in whatever way you have them, and they can be prepared with SQL - use this example and you should be on your way:

http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html